# angular scope in controllers + directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to angular and I'm having an issue with scope between my directive and controller. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.doSomething = function() {
       alert("Testing Scope");
   };
});
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('keyEvents', function($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $document.on('keypress', function(e) {
                 switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case (49):
                            doSomething();
                            break    

                    default:
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
          }; 
        });
```

HTML:

```
     <script src= "js/main.js"></script>
     <script src = "js/keyevents.js"></script>

     <body ng-app ="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
               <div key-events>
               </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

I am getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined - how do I use the doSomething function inside my directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
doSomething();
```

Should be

```
scope.doSomething();
```

Because when you define a method in a scope from a controller and this scope is inherited in a directive, you can access it only through `scope` passed as an argument.